# How to restrict the access to the certain domains during work hours automatically

Tags: iptables, hosts

I know about SelfControl app, but it has to be started everytime and the block hours to be set.

I want for example to forbid loading certain sites during work hours, but make it possible during the rest. I want to set it once and forget. It has to do the switch automatically everyday.

What would be the easier way to do this, considering that i'm a super newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you looking at something like Dansguardian:

http://dansguardian.org/

The documentation is quite good and there some resources on time based browsing restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, that will do but it kinda looks like a overkill for my super simple needs.
Infact i need to block just 1-2 sites from 9 to 5 that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

We'll use a combination of Iptables, Bash Scripting and Cron to achieve this.

## Iptables

Iptables command to block a domain looks like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: yourdomain.com" --algo bm -j DROP
```

Similarly, unblock command looks like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: yourdomain.com" --algo bm -j ACCEPT
```

## Bash Scripts

Make a file, say, `block.sh`, in which you define Iptables rules to block outgoing connections the domains you want to block, and a reverse script to unblock them.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: yourdomain.com" --algo bm -j DROP
# other stuff you want to do when you block a domain
# add blocking commands for each domain here
```

Run `chmod +x block.sh` to make the script executable. Now you can run it as `/path/to/file/block.sh`.

Thus, you'll have two scripts like:

1. `/path/to/block.sh`
2. `/path/to/unblock.sh`

## Cron

Now, add a crontab entry to run your scripts like this:

Run `crontab-e`. In first run, it'll ask you to configure a text editor. Use nano, if you are not sure.

Add these lines to the end of the file:

```
0 9 * * * /path/to/block.sh
0 17 * * * /path/to/unblock.sh
```

Save the file with `CTRL+O`, press `ENTER` and then, `CTRL+X` to exit.

Now, at 9 am everyday, the first script will block all the domains, and at 5 pm, the second script will unblock them back.